# RxJava 2 detect unconsumed elements

Tags: java, rx-java2

I'm new to RxJava so hopefully this makes sense.

I'm retrofitting an old queuing system with RxJava.  The structure is we have a single database table that has a bunch of jobs to be run.

What I want to happen:

- Poll the db for new jobs.
- filter/flatmap incoming jobs to the processors that care about those job types
- handle those jobs in whatever way is appropriate
- Log off errors and unhandled jobs.

Here is what I have so far

```
    Flowable<Job> jobQueue = Flowable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io())
            .onBackpressureDrop()
            .flatMapIterable((l)->dao.getNextSetOfJobs(100), 1000)
            .retry(5);

    jobQueue.flatMap((t) ->
    {
        if ("myJob".equals(t.getJobType()))
        {
            return Flowable.just("rightJob");
        }
        else
            return Flowable.empty();
    }).subscribe((v)->System.out.println(v));

    jobQueue.flatMap((t) ->
    {
        if ("myOtherJob".equals(t.getJobType()))
        {
            return Flowable.just("rightJob");
        }
        else
            return Flowable.empty();
    }).subscribe((v)->System.out.println(v));
```

So my questions.

- How do I catch the case where `JobType` isn't handled downstream?
- Is this the right way to do subscriptions?  That is, filter/flatmap out the jobs that I care about and then push them down into a processor that does the "right" thing.
- Should I be replaying and filtering?
- Is there another pattern or book I should be reading or applying?

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the case where JobType isn't handled downstream" ? Is that because your filtering aren't being done from the same place / class? I have the intuition you could use rx `groupBy` to organize by `JobType`, but it depends on the implementation.

Comment: I think you could do something like: `jobQueue.groupBy(Job::getJobType).subscribe(grouped -> /* process according to group key */)`

Comment: That was the initial thought but I could definitely revisit it (grouping is probably what I'm really looking for).

Comment: The main problem is that there are 20 different job types doing wildly different things.  So that grouping method might get a little hairy looking.  IDK though, I could probably still wrangle it into something good.

Comment: I think one thing that is wrong in your `filter`-based approach is that it necessitate several calls to `subscribe`, whereas you should have only one.